# "Derivative" of a Radon measure?

Tags: functional-analysis, measure-theory

I am looking for an intuitive interpretation of the following expression:

Let $\nu $ be a Radon measure on $\mathbb{R}^d$ and define

$lim_{r\rightarrow 0} c_r$ with $c_r := \frac{\nu (A \cap B_r(x))}{\nu (B_r(x))}$ if $\nu (B_r(x)) > 0$ and $0$ else for $A\subset \mathbb{R}^d$.

It looks like perhaps a derivative... but I really don't know...

Comment: Ok, I somewhere find a similar expression called "approximate" density of the set $A$. But nonetheless I am still looking for an interpretation..

Comment: Furthermore I am confronted with showing in the setting above that there exist a $\mu$-null set $N$ s.t. the limit above exists and takes the value $0$ and $1$ outside of $N$. I really don't see the sense because $N$ does not appear at all in $c_r$...?!?